# WS02 ESB - How to acquire 'Proxy Service' Statistics

Tags: wso2-esb

I believe that `Proxy Services` not being Sequences don't have statistics facilities. I core requirement I have is to acquire statistics & service availability stats for my Proxies. What is the standard approach? Wrap a `Proxy Service` within a Sequence? Is there an example of this?

Also The `Monitor/Mediation Statistics` page has a section `Proxy Service Statistics`, is there a means to turning on `Proxy Service` stats that I have missed. if not, exactly where does this data derive?

Comment: Solved. Should have re-read the docs (again). I believe the endpoint needs to be defined under 'Service bus / Endpoints' & given a name in the registry. The 'Proxy Service' must then the reference the endpoint via the registry (not inline which was my first approach). Finally the 'Proxy Service' source xml has attribute 'statistics', setting it to enable. Results in the Mediation Service showing the 'Proxy Service' statistics.

Answer (score 0):

To enable statistics for a mediation component using the Synapse configuration language, set the value of the "statistics" attribute to "enabled" on the sequence, proxy or endpoint configuration as mentioned in  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Monitoring+the+ESB document.

Here is a sample proxy which enabled statistics.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="oldmac"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="enable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>

        <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.google.com"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```